# When loggers are setup using log4j2 config file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have created a log4j2.xml file. When is it used to initiate and configure loggers ? At the time JVM is started ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Log4J1**

From the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) of Log4J1, there are two cases where the configuration is initiated:

1. You can programatically initialize all the configuration calling `BasicConfigurator.configure();` in your application
2. The automatically configuration will look at the classpath to find the configuration file. This is a excerpt from the documentation:

> The log4j library does not make any assumptions about its environment.
> In particular, there are no default log4j appenders. Under certain
> well-defined circumstances however, the static inializer of the Logger
> class will attempt to automatically configure log4j. The Java language
> guarantees that the static initializer of a class is called once and
> only once during the loading of a class into memory. It is important
> to remember that different classloaders may load distinct copies of
> the same class. These copies of the same class are considered as
> totally unrelated by the JVM.

## **Log4J2**

In log4J2, they have changed the way you inilitaze programatically, you can found a plenty of ways [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html). The automatically way does not see to have changed, so, its loaded when the static block is loaded by the JVM. You can see how it looks to the config file [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html). From the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) of log4j2:

> Log4j has the ability to automatically configure itself during
> initialization. When Log4j starts it will locate all the
> ConfigurationFactory plugins and arrange them in weighted order from
> highest to lowest. As delivered, Log4j contains four
> ConfigurationFactory implementations: one for JSON, one for YAML, one
> for properties, and one for XML.

Comment: I am asking in reference to log4j2. Your answer is for log4j1.

Comment: I'look for a documentation to log4j2, but I believe its the samething @Andy897

Comment: BasicConfigurator does not exist in log4j2

Comment: @Andy897, I have edited the answer to contain information about log4j2.